# How to use tox and py.test to limit the unittests to the supported platforms?

Tags: python, setuptools, pytest, tox

I do have a small python package [tendo](https://github.com/ssbarnea/tendopy) that I want to make it run, test and install on a wide range of python versions, starting with 2.5 and ending with 3.2

I need 2.5 support because we still have machines running it and that cannot be upgraded yet.

Currently the unittests are included inside the modules, this making easier to update them when you change the module and also to run them, because **main** would run the tests.

Some modules are not available on all platforms.

```
setup.py
setup.cfg
tox.ini
mypackage/foo.py
mypackage/bar.py
```

Tox is configured to run `py.test` on all platforms, still the `[pytest]` section from `setup.cfg` is configured to look for tests inside all `*.py` files.

This brings a problem: some of these files are not supposed to run on `py25` and it's impossible to tune them for that.

I am looking for a configuration which would let me specify which modules to load (or better exclude) for some platforms.

The desired behaviour is to be able to install this package on all supported versions of python. (Obviously few module should be skipped).

Answer (score 2):

You can use conftest.py files to customize test collection.  For example, you can skip setup.py on all versions and a specific module on python3 like this::

```
# content of conftest.py
import sys

collect_ignore = ["setup.py"]
if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    collect_ignore.append("pkg/module_py2.py")
```

If you put this conftest.py file next to your setup.py file and have a module file like this::

```
# content of pkg/module_py2.py
def test_only_on_python2():
    try:
        assert 0
    except Exception, e:
        pass
```

Then you see with `py.test --collectonly` under Python2 something like this::

```
$ py.test --collectonly
=========================== test session starts ============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.2.5.dev1
collecting ... collected 1 items
<Module 'pkg/module_py2.py'>
  <Function 'test_only_on_python2'>

=============================  in 0.01 seconds =============================
```

According to the conftest.py definition the module is seen whereas 
under python3 neither the `module_py2.py` nor `setup.py` file will be collected.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option, which I personally prefer:

```
import os.path
import sys

py3 = sys.version_info[0] >= 3

def pytest_ignore_collect(path, config):
    basename = os.path.basename(str(path))
    return (not py3 and 'py3' in basename) or (py3 and 'py2' in basename)
```

Adding `py2` or `py3` to test files will then only collect them for testing under their respective Python versions.